# Error i915: drm_WARN_ON(new_crtc_state->do_async_flip && !plane->async_flip)

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, intel-graphics, i915

I'm getting this kernel error on 5.19 **and 6.0** **and 6.1** all the time, is there anything that can be done to mitigate it. Seems like it's a i915 driver problem. The screen frequently goes black.

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
i915 0000:00:02.0: drm_WARN_ON(new_crtc_state->do_async_flip && !plane->async_flip)
WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 1565 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_display.c:7505 intel_atomic_check+0x2947/0x2fe0 [i915]
Modules linked in: tun snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib usbhid snd_rawmidi hid_logitech_hidpp uhid veth nf_conntrack_netlink xt_nat xt_tcpudp ip_vs_sh ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_rr ip_vs nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE vxlan ip6_udp_tunnel udp_tunnel nft_log nft_limit ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_limit xt_NFLOG nfnetlink_log xt_physdev xt_conntrack xt_mark xt_multiport xt_addrtype xt_comment nft_compat nf_tables ip_set nfnetlink iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c br_netfilter bridge stp llc ctr ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device overlay qrtr bnep snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp binfmt_misc snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_sof_probes nls_ascii nls_cp437 vfat fat snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_soc_dmic snd_hda_codec_generic mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence
 x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_sof_intel_hda intel_powerclamp snd_sof_pci coretemp snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof kvm_intel snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda btusb snd_hda_ext_core btrtl snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi kvm btbcm iwlmvm snd_soc_core btintel btmtk irqbypass snd_compress snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi intel_cstate bluetooth mac80211 snd_hda_codec intel_uncore snd_hda_core iTCO_wdt snd_hwdep intel_pmc_bxt libarc4 serio_raw pcspkr efi_pstore soundwire_bus jitterentropy_rng iTCO_vendor_support mei_me wmi_bmof iwlwifi snd_pcm watchdog sha512_ssse3 mei sha512_generic snd_timer uvcvideo drbg ansi_cprng videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops ucsi_acpi processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy cfg80211 videobuf2_v4l2 typec_ucsi processor_thermal_device ecdh_generic processor_thermal_rfim videobuf2_common ecc roles processor_thermal_mbox processor_thermal_rapl typec intel_rapl_common intel_soc_dts_iosf thinkpad_acpi nvram platform_profile ledtrig_audio snd soundcore rfkill
 int3403_thermal soc_button_array int340x_thermal_zone ac evdev int3400_thermal intel_pmc_core acpi_tad acpi_thermal_rel intel_hid acpi_pad sparse_keymap v4l2loopback(OE) videodev mc msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport fuse configfs efivarfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic dm_crypt dm_mod hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub hid_generic intel_ishtp_hid hid i915 drm_buddy crc32_pclmul i2c_algo_bit crc32c_intel drm_display_helper ghash_clmulni_intel cec nvme rc_core nvme_core ttm t10_pi xhci_pci drm_kms_helper crc64_rocksoft_generic crc64_rocksoft crc_t10dif xhci_hcd crct10dif_generic aesni_intel i2c_i801 intel_ish_ipc crct10dif_pclmul crc64 crypto_simd usbcore drm psmouse thunderbolt cryptd i2c_smbus intel_ishtp usb_common crct10dif_common wmi button battery video
CPU: 4 PID: 1565 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W  OE     5.19.0-2-amd64 #1  Debian 5.19.11-1
Hardware name: LENOVO 20XW003GUS/20XW003GUS, BIOS N32ET80W (1.56 ) 08/29/2022
RIP: 0010:intel_atomic_check+0x2947/0x2fe0 [i915]
Code: 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b 27 e8 42 e6 e5 cd 48 c7 c1 80 c1 b4 c0 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c7 0b c6 b6 c0 48 89 c6 e8 5d d4 11 ce <0f> 0b c7 45 a0 ea ff ff ff e9 9e de ff ff 49 8b 47 08 48 8b 88 90
RSP: 0018:ffffa8e5c1d6fbb8 EFLAGS: 00010286
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000000
RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffffff8f36ee29 RDI: 00000000ffffffff
RBP: ffffa8e5c1d6fc60 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000100bda3eb
R10: ffffa8e5c1d6fa58 R11: ffffffff8fabfd28 R12: ffff9c48c1b433d0
R13: ffffffffc0400ed0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff9c49a42f1800
FS:  00007fd13281fa80(0000) GS:ffff9c4c0f700000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 000022a80162a000 CR3: 0000000128634004 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
PKRU: 55555554
Call Trace:
 <TASK>
 drm_atomic_check_only+0x5b1/0xa20 [drm]
 drm_atomic_nonblocking_commit+0x13/0x60 [drm]
 drm_atomic_helper_page_flip+0x60/0xd0 [drm_kms_helper]
 drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x573/0x5d0 [drm]
 ? drm_mode_cursor2_ioctl+0x10/0x10 [drm]
 drm_ioctl_kernel+0xb2/0x140 [drm]
 drm_ioctl+0x224/0x3e0 [drm]
 ? drm_mode_cursor2_ioctl+0x10/0x10 [drm]
 __x64_sys_ioctl+0x87/0xc0
 do_syscall_64+0x38/0xc0
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
RIP: 0033:0x7fd1322ffe9b
Code: 00 48 89 44 24 18 31 c0 48 8d 44 24 60 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8d 44 24 20 48 89 44 24 10 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <41> 89 c0 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 1b 48 8b 44 24 18 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00
RSP: 002b:00007ffc0b2255b0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000559f70456b50 RCX: 00007fd1322ffe9b
RDX: 00007ffc0b225640 RSI: 00000000c01864b0 RDI: 000000000000000d
RBP: 00007ffc0b225640 R08: 000000000019c78d R09: 0000559f7041f010
R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000c01864b0
R13: 000000000000000d R14: 0000559f70458630 R15: 000000000019c78d
 </TASK>
---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

This is from version [20210818-1 of `firmware-misc-nonfree` from Debian 11 - Bookworm](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/firmware-misc-nonfree)

```
❯ modinfo i915
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-2-amd64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
import_ns:      DMA_BUF
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, but on Arch Linux.
This only happens to me while playing **the anime game**.
I suggest disabling PSR (panel self refresh), by adding `i915.enable_psr=0` to kernel parameters. It works on Arch, but it taints the kernel for some reason.
Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Intel_graphics#Screen_flickering

`i915 0000:00:02.0: drm_WARN_ON(new_crtc_state->do_async_flip && !plane->async_flip)` appears 4415 times in the log file.
Here's an excerpt:

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
i915 0000:00:02.0: drm_WARN_ON(new_crtc_state->do_async_flip && !plane->async_flip)
WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 814 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_display.c:6544 intel_atomic_check+0x2acc/0x2c60 [i915]
Modules linked in: uinput uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_usb_audio videodev snd_usbmidi_lib videobuf2_common snd_rawmidi mc hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid udp_diag tcp_diag inet_diag ccm rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet mii cdc_acm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg nf_nat_tftp nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_conntrack_tftp nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_tables ip6table_nat ip6table_mangle ip6table_raw ip6table_security iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security nfnetlink ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bnep snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils
 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_idt snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_generic snd_compress ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp ac97_bus mac80211 coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_intel_sdw_acpi irqbypass btusb snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul btrtl iwlwifi polyval_clmulni snd_hda_core vfat btbcm fat polyval_generic mousedev btintel gf128mul snd_hwdep processor_thermal_device_pci ghash_clmulni_intel cros_ec_sysfs cros_ec_chardev cros_ec_debugfs btmtk sha512_ssse3 processor_thermal_device cros_ec_dev processor_thermal_rfim ucsi_acpi snd_pcm cfg80211 aesni_intel pmt_telemetry iTCO_wdt bluetooth crypto_simd intel_pmc_bxt processor_thermal_mbox mei_wdt cryptd mei_hdcp mei_pxp hid_multitouch iTCO_vendor_support spi_nor pmt_class snd_timer cros_ec_lpcs processor_thermal_rapl joydev typec_ucsi rapl intel_cstate
 ecdh_generic intel_rapl_msr cros_ec psmouse intel_uncore wmi_bmof typec crc16 mtd snd mei_me i2c_i801 i2c_hid_acpi intel_rapl_common rfkill thunderbolt int3403_thermal i2c_smbus int3400_thermal intel_vsec roles soundcore mei i2c_hid int340x_thermal_zone igen6_edac acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid usbip_host usbip_core dm_multipath sg crypto_user fuse dm_mod loop ip_tables x_tables btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq libcrc32c crc32c_generic serio_raw atkbd libps2 nvme vivaldi_fmap intel_lpss_pci nvme_core i8042 xhci_pci spi_intel_pci intel_lpss crc32c_intel spi_intel nvme_common xhci_pci_renesas idma64 serio i915 drm_buddy intel_gtt video wmi drm_display_helper cec ttm
CPU: 6 PID: 814 Comm: Xorg Kdump: loaded Not tainted 6.2.11-zen1-1-zen #1 7256d3b1cb5c5f7946c603b69d5d9e33bff385df
Hardware name: Framework Laptop (12th Gen Intel Core)/FRANMACP04, BIOS 03.05 08/23/2022
RIP: 0010:intel_atomic_check+0x2acc/0x2c60 [i915]
Code: 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b 27 e8 8d 2a af f4 48 c7 c1 d8 cd 83 c0 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c7 7a 3f 86 c0 48 89 c6 e8 f4 c1 1c f4 <0f> 0b e9 41 ea ff ff 4d 8b 4e 20 45 8b 46 60 48 89 c6 48 85 c0 74
RSP: 0018:ffffa66605a8fb50 EFLAGS: 00010286
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8a416233d800 RCX: 0000000000000027
RDX: ffff8a425f9a1648 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff8a425f9a1640
RBP: ffffa66605a8fc08 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00000000ffffffea
R10: ffffffffb6859a80 R11: 00000000fffff6a8 R12: ffff8a3ec278c260
R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff8a3eca8fd800 R15: 0000000000000000
FS:  00007fa99979d440(0000) GS:ffff8a425f980000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 000000005d2cf6c0 CR3: 0000000122d28006 CR4: 0000000000f70ee0
PKRU: 55555554
Call Trace:
 <TASK>
 ? drm_framebuffer_init+0x157/0x200
 ? slab_post_alloc_hook.constprop.0+0x3a/0x260
 ? slab_post_alloc_hook.constprop.0+0x3a/0x260
 drm_atomic_check_only+0x60e/0xa30
 drm_atomic_nonblocking_commit+0x17/0x70
 drm_atomic_helper_page_flip+0xea/0x150
 drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x5ab/0x600
 ? __pfx_drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x10/0x10
 drm_ioctl_kernel+0xca/0x170
 drm_ioctl+0x233/0x410
 ? __pfx_drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x10/0x10
 __x64_sys_ioctl+0x91/0xd0
 do_syscall_64+0x5c/0x90
 ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2c/0x1d0
 ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x72/0xdc
RIP: 0033:0x7fa99a16e53f
Code: 00 48 89 44 24 18 31 c0 48 8d 44 24 60 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8d 44 24 20 48 89 44 24 10 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <89> c2 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 18 48 8b 44 24 18 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00
RSP: 002b:00007fffaab0b9c0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055e2e76de3f0 RCX: 00007fa99a16e53f
RDX: 00007fffaab0ba50 RSI: 00000000c01864b0 RDI: 0000000000000013
RBP: 00007fffaab0ba50 R08: 00000000000c0e85 R09: 0000000000000003
R10: 000055e2e757e010 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000c01864b0
R13: 0000000000000013 R14: 000055e2e75b8c20 R15: 0000000000000122
 </TASK>
---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
------------[ cut here ]------------
i915 0000:00:02.0: drm_WARN_ON(new_crtc_state->do_async_flip && !plane->async_flip)
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 814 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_display.c:6544 intel_atomic_check+0x2acc/0x2c60 [i915]
Modules linked in: uinput uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_usb_audio videodev snd_usbmidi_lib videobuf2_common snd_rawmidi mc hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid udp_diag tcp_diag inet_diag ccm rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet mii cdc_acm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg nf_nat_tftp nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_conntrack_tftp nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_tables ip6table_nat ip6table_mangle ip6table_raw ip6table_security iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security nfnetlink ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bnep snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils
 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_idt snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_generic snd_compress ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp ac97_bus mac80211 coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_intel_sdw_acpi irqbypass btusb snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul btrtl iwlwifi polyval_clmulni snd_hda_core vfat btbcm fat polyval_generic mousedev btintel gf128mul snd_hwdep processor_thermal_device_pci ghash_clmulni_intel cros_ec_sysfs cros_ec_chardev cros_ec_debugfs btmtk sha512_ssse3 processor_thermal_device cros_ec_dev processor_thermal_rfim ucsi_acpi snd_pcm cfg80211 aesni_intel pmt_telemetry iTCO_wdt bluetooth crypto_simd intel_pmc_bxt processor_thermal_mbox mei_wdt cryptd mei_hdcp mei_pxp hid_multitouch iTCO_vendor_support spi_nor pmt_class snd_timer cros_ec_lpcs processor_thermal_rapl joydev typec_ucsi rapl intel_cstate
 ecdh_generic intel_rapl_msr cros_ec psmouse intel_uncore wmi_bmof typec crc16 mtd snd mei_me i2c_i801 i2c_hid_acpi intel_rapl_common rfkill thunderbolt int3403_thermal i2c_smbus int3400_thermal intel_vsec roles soundcore mei i2c_hid int340x_thermal_zone igen6_edac acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid usbip_host usbip_core dm_multipath sg crypto_user fuse dm_mod loop ip_tables x_tables btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq libcrc32c crc32c_generic serio_raw atkbd libps2 nvme vivaldi_fmap intel_lpss_pci nvme_core i8042 xhci_pci spi_intel_pci intel_lpss crc32c_intel spi_intel nvme_common xhci_pci_renesas idma64 serio i915 drm_buddy intel_gtt video wmi drm_display_helper cec ttm
CPU: 0 PID: 814 Comm: Xorg Kdump: loaded Tainted: G        W          6.2.11-zen1-1-zen #1 7256d3b1cb5c5f7946c603b69d5d9e33bff385df
Hardware name: Framework Laptop (12th Gen Intel Core)/FRANMACP04, BIOS 03.05 08/23/2022
RIP: 0010:intel_atomic_check+0x2acc/0x2c60 [i915]
Code: 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b 27 e8 8d 2a af f4 48 c7 c1 d8 cd 83 c0 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c7 7a 3f 86 c0 48 89 c6 e8 f4 c1 1c f4 <0f> 0b e9 41 ea ff ff 4d 8b 4e 20 45 8b 46 60 48 89 c6 48 85 c0 74
RSP: 0018:ffffa66605a8fb58 EFLAGS: 00010286
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8a41ba64b000 RCX: 0000000000000027
RDX: ffff8a425f821648 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff8a425f821640
RBP: ffffa66605a8fc10 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00000000ffffffea
R10: ffffffffb6859a80 R11: 00000000fffff6d8 R12: ffff8a3ec278c260
R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff8a3eca8fd800 R15: 0000000000000000
FS:  00007fa99979d440(0000) GS:ffff8a425f800000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 000000004cbb1000 CR3: 0000000122d28001 CR4: 0000000000f70ef0
PKRU: 55555554
Call Trace:
 <TASK>
 ? slab_post_alloc_hook.constprop.0+0x3a/0x260
 ? slab_post_alloc_hook.constprop.0+0x3a/0x260
 drm_atomic_check_only+0x60e/0xa30
 drm_atomic_nonblocking_commit+0x17/0x70
 drm_atomic_helper_page_flip+0xea/0x150
 drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x5ab/0x600
 ? __pfx_drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x10/0x10
 drm_ioctl_kernel+0xca/0x170
 drm_ioctl+0x233/0x410
 ? __pfx_drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x10/0x10
 __x64_sys_ioctl+0x91/0xd0
 do_syscall_64+0x5c/0x90
 ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
 ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
 ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
 ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x72/0xdc
RIP: 0033:0x7fa99a16e53f
Code: 00 48 89 44 24 18 31 c0 48 8d 44 24 60 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8d 44 24 20 48 89 44 24 10 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <89> c2 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 18 48 8b 44 24 18 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00
RSP: 002b:00007fffaab0b9c0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055e2e76de3f0 RCX: 00007fa99a16e53f
RDX: 00007fffaab0ba50 RSI: 00000000c01864b0 RDI: 0000000000000013
RBP: 00007fffaab0ba50 R08: 00000000000c0e89 R09: 0000000000000003
R10: 000055e2e757e010 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000c01864b0
R13: 0000000000000013 R14: 000055e2e75b8c20 R15: 00000000000000ee
 </TASK>
---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
------------[ cut here ]------------
i915 0000:00:02.0: drm_WARN_ON(new_crtc_state->do_async_flip && !plane->async_flip)
WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 814 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_display.c:6544 intel_atomic_check+0x2acc/0x2c60 [i915]
Modules linked in: uinput uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 snd_usb_audio videodev snd_usbmidi_lib videobuf2_common snd_rawmidi mc hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid udp_diag tcp_diag inet_diag ccm rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet mii cdc_acm rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg nf_nat_tftp nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_conntrack_tftp nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib nft_reject_inet nf_reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_tables ip6table_nat ip6table_mangle ip6table_raw ip6table_security iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security nfnetlink ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bnep snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils
 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus iwlmvm snd_hda_codec_idt snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_generic snd_compress ledtrig_audio x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp ac97_bus mac80211 coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel libarc4 snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_intel_sdw_acpi irqbypass btusb snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul btrtl iwlwifi polyval_clmulni snd_hda_core vfat btbcm fat polyval_generic mousedev btintel gf128mul snd_hwdep processor_thermal_device_pci ghash_clmulni_intel cros_ec_sysfs cros_ec_chardev cros_ec_debugfs btmtk sha512_ssse3 processor_thermal_device cros_ec_dev processor_thermal_rfim ucsi_acpi snd_pcm cfg80211 aesni_intel pmt_telemetry iTCO_wdt bluetooth crypto_simd intel_pmc_bxt processor_thermal_mbox mei_wdt cryptd mei_hdcp mei_pxp hid_multitouch iTCO_vendor_support spi_nor pmt_class snd_timer cros_ec_lpcs processor_thermal_rapl joydev typec_ucsi rapl intel_cstate
 ecdh_generic intel_rapl_msr cros_ec psmouse intel_uncore wmi_bmof typec crc16 mtd snd mei_me i2c_i801 i2c_hid_acpi intel_rapl_common rfkill thunderbolt int3403_thermal i2c_smbus int3400_thermal intel_vsec roles soundcore mei i2c_hid int340x_thermal_zone igen6_edac acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid usbip_host usbip_core dm_multipath sg crypto_user fuse dm_mod loop ip_tables x_tables btrfs blake2b_generic xor raid6_pq libcrc32c crc32c_generic serio_raw atkbd libps2 nvme vivaldi_fmap intel_lpss_pci nvme_core i8042 xhci_pci spi_intel_pci intel_lpss crc32c_intel spi_intel nvme_common xhci_pci_renesas idma64 serio i915 drm_buddy intel_gtt video wmi drm_display_helper cec ttm
CPU: 6 PID: 814 Comm: Xorg Kdump: loaded Tainted: G        W          6.2.11-zen1-1-zen #1 7256d3b1cb5c5f7946c603b69d5d9e33bff385df
Hardware name: Framework Laptop (12th Gen Intel Core)/FRANMACP04, BIOS 03.05 08/23/2022
RIP: 0010:intel_atomic_check+0x2acc/0x2c60 [i915]
Code: 4c 8b 67 50 4d 85 e4 75 03 4c 8b 27 e8 8d 2a af f4 48 c7 c1 d8 cd 83 c0 4c 89 e2 48 c7 c7 7a 3f 86 c0 48 89 c6 e8 f4 c1 1c f4 <0f> 0b e9 41 ea ff ff 4d 8b 4e 20 45 8b 46 60 48 89 c6 48 85 c0 74
RSP: 0018:ffffa66605a8fad0 EFLAGS: 00010282
RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8a416233e800 RCX: 0000000000000027
RDX: ffff8a425f9a1648 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff8a425f9a1640
RBP: ffffa66605a8fb88 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 00000000ffffffea
R10: ffffffffb6859a80 R11: 00000000fffff709 R12: ffff8a3ec278c260
R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff8a3eca8fd800 R15: 0000000000000000
FS:  00007fa99979d440(0000) GS:ffff8a425f980000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: 00007f8a4ec9f000 CR3: 0000000122d28006 CR4: 0000000000f70ee0
PKRU: 55555554
Call Trace:
 <TASK>
 ? slab_post_alloc_hook.constprop.0+0x3a/0x260
 ? slab_post_alloc_hook.constprop.0+0x3a/0x260
 drm_atomic_check_only+0x60e/0xa30
 drm_atomic_nonblocking_commit+0x17/0x70
 drm_atomic_helper_page_flip+0xea/0x150
 drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x5ab/0x600
 ? __pfx_drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x10/0x10
 drm_ioctl_kernel+0xca/0x170
 drm_ioctl+0x233/0x410
 ? __pfx_drm_mode_page_flip_ioctl+0x10/0x10
 __x64_sys_ioctl+0x91/0xd0
 do_syscall_64+0x5c/0x90
 ? ptrace_may_access+0x108/0x180
 ? __do_sys_kcmp+0x1f7/0x520
 ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2c/0x1d0
 ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
 ? do_syscall_64+0x6b/0x90
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x72/0xdc
RIP: 0033:0x7fa99a16e53f
Code: 00 48 89 44 24 18 31 c0 48 8d 44 24 60 c7 04 24 10 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8d 44 24 20 48 89 44 24 10 b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <89> c2 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 18 48 8b 44 24 18 64 48 2b 04 25 28 00 00
RSP: 002b:00007fffaab0b9c0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055e2e76de3f0 RCX: 00007fa99a16e53f
RDX: 00007fffaab0ba50 RSI: 00000000c01864b0 RDI: 0000000000000013
RBP: 00007fffaab0ba50 R08: 00000000000c0e8c R09: 000000055e2e864f
R10: 000055e2e757e010 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000c01864b0
R13: 0000000000000013 R14: 000055e2e75b8c20 R15: 0000000000000121
 </TASK>
---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

and so on.